# Finding width and height of concave curved shaped blob

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have been scratching my head over this problem of calculating the width and height measurements of a figure like this. The major challenge is I cant use miBoundingrectangle and cant figure out a way for bounding from inside, either way I'll lose some pixels for height and width measurement.

Sample Input:

[image]

Sample Output:

[image]

Is there any fail proof way to get an accurate dimension measurement?

Below is a solution i was trying out to find inner bounding max rectangle.

```
_,contour2,_=cv2.findContours(im,cv2.RETR_CCOMP,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
for c in contour2:
    area=cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area ==25224.0:
        print(area)
        n = np.squeeze(contour2[0])

        x = sorted(n, key=lambda a:a[0])
        left = x[0]
        right = x[-1]
        print("",left,right)
        y= sorted(n, key=lambda a:a[1])
        top = y[0]
        bottom = y[-1]
        cv2.drawContours(im,[c],-1,(128,128,128),2)
        cv2.circle(im, (left[0],left[1]), 4, (128,128,128), 8)
        cv2.circle(im, (right[0],right[1]), 4, (128,128,128), 8)
        cv2.circle(im, (top[0],top[1]), 4, (128,128,128), 8)
        cv2.circle(im, (bottom[0],bottom[1]), 4, (128,128,128), 8)

        roi_w = int(np.sqrt((top[0]-right[0])*(top[0]-right[0])(top[1]-right[1])*(top[1]-right[1])))
        roi_h = int(np.sqrt((top[0]-left[0])*(top[0]-left[0])+(top[1]-left[1])*(top[1]-left[1])))
                pts1 = np.float32([top,right,left])

        new_top = top
        new_right = [top[0] + roi_w, top[1]]
        new_left = [top[0], top[1] + roi_h]
        pts2 = np.float32([new_top,new_right,new_left])

     cv2.imshow("threshed", im)`
```

Comment: Could you add your input image?

Comment: Sorry , made the edit :)

Comment: Could you elaborate on what minimum width and row you're trying to get as in the center width or height?

Comment: yes the width and height from centroid(center) in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an OpenCV solution. The main idea is

- Convert image to grayscale and invert image
- Find contour and centroid of the blob
- Use Numpy slicing to grab all row/column pixels
- Count non-zero pixels to determine width/height

---

We convert the image to grayscale and invert it. This is the image we will count pixels on since the desired ROI is in white. From here, we find the contour of the blob and the center coordinates using [`cv2.moments()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html). This gives us the *centroid* (i.e., the center (x, y)-coordinates of the object)

```
M = cv2.moments(c)
cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
```

Next we use Numpy slicing to obtain all the row and column pixels. We use `cv2.countNonZero()` to find the width/height of the row/column like this

```
row_pixels = cv2.countNonZero(gray[cY][:])
column_pixels = cv2.countNonZero(gray[:, cX])
```

Here's a visualization

[image]

Here's the result

> row 150
>
> column 354

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('1.png')
inverted = 255 - image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = 255 - gray

cnts = cv2.findContours(gray, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

for c in cnts:
    M = cv2.moments(c)
    cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
    cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])

    cv2.circle(inverted, (cX, cY), 5, (36, 255, 12), -1)
    inverted[cY][:] = (36, 255, 12)
    inverted[:, cX] = (36, 255, 12)
    row_pixels = cv2.countNonZero(gray[cY][:])
    column_pixels = cv2.countNonZero(gray[:, cX])

print('row', row_pixels)
print('column', column_pixels)
cv2.imshow('inverted', inverted)
cv2.imwrite('inverted.png', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Cant thank enough for the help . Thank you so much !

Comment: Nice OpenCV solution using the image moment to get the centroid and then counting rows and column pixels from there. Very clean and simple! It is very close to my ADDITION, but you use the centroid rather than my center of the bounding box.

Answer (score 2):

This is an Imagemagick solution. But the concept will give you a clue how to proceed with OpenCV. It is not quite the dimensions you want. But the closest way I could conceive. Basically, it is the **maximum inside bounding box**. Perhaps there is something similar in OpenCV.

Iterate around each edge of the image from outside towards the inside until each remaining edge is fully black with no white (or reasonably close to that).

Input:

[image]

```
convert img.png -threshold 0 -define trim:percent-background=0% -trim +repage -format "%wx%h" +write info: result.png

returns: widthxheight => 144x317
```

[image]

ADDITION:

Here is another solution that should be easy to do in OpenCV.

Trim to get the **minimum outer bounding box**. Extract the center row and column, which may have some white on the ends. Then pad with white all around. Then trim all the white again so you have one black row and column remaining with no white. Then get the dimensions of the single black row and single black column.

```
width=`convert img.png -threshold 0 -trim +repage -gravity center -crop x1+0+0 +repage -bordercolor white -border 1x1 -trim +repage -format "%w" info:`
height=`convert img.png -threshold 0 -trim +repage -gravity center -crop 1x+0+0 +repage -bordercolor white -border 1x1 -trim +repage -format "%h" info:`
echo "width=$width; height=$height;"
returns: => width=145; height=352;
```

Comment: `@nathancy` Thanks. See my ADDITION for an alternate solution using the dimension of the center row and column after trimming to the minimum outer bounding box. I suppose one also could take the average of the two approaches.

Comment: That seems doable and makes a lot of sense. Thanks :). I was still thinking if there was some function or a specific method in opencv to get this through. But thank you for your lucid explanation.